# rails2 ruby geocoder issue when finding the distance

Tags: ruby, rails-geocoder

I'm using ruby geocoder gem in my rails2 app. When a user tries to sign up i'm taking his ip and fetching lat and long using geocoder. Next, taking user entered address and fetching lat and longitude. Finally checking the distance between those two.If distance is greater than 100 am adding an error. This is happening in before_create callback(As per clients requirement). But the issue here is geocoder is sending continuous requests and breaking.Below is my code.

Given some dummy address and ip for testing purpose.

```
  def validate_address_and_ip

    p "validate_address_and_ip"
    dup_addr = "Level 8, Umiya Business Bay Tower 1,Cessna Business Park, Maratahalli ORR,Sarjapur Ring Road, Kadubeesanahalli,Bangalore"
    ip_based_lat_lng = Geocoder.search("183.82.98.134").map{ |obj| [obj.latitude, obj.longitude] }.flatten#ip_address
    p "ip_based_lat_lng=", ip_based_lat_lng
    addr_results = Geocoder.search(dup_addr)#address.full_address
    addr_based_result = addr_results.first.geometry["location"]
    lat,lang = addr_based_result["lat"], addr_based_result["lng"]
    dist_in_miles = Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(ip_based_lat_lng, [lat, lang]).round

    puts "***************#{dist_in_miles}*******************************"
    if 300 > 100
      p "*****************in if condition**********************"
      self.errors.add_to_base('zip code and IP mismatch.')
      return false
      puts "***************#{self.errors}*******************************"
    end
  end

Error: Numerical argument out of domain - sqrt
```

in log am getting

"validate_address_and_ip"
"ip_based_lat_lng="
[17.3753, 78.4744]
***************311******************************
"****************in if condition**********************"
"validate_address_and_ip"
Geocoding API not responding fast enough (use Geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...) to set limit).
"ip_based_lat_lng="
[]

Why is that method getting called multiple times? Can anyone tell me the issue

Comment: could you please add the whole stacktrace. your code works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah code is fine and there is no crash also. DOn't know the resaon but this method is getting called many times and getting 
Geocoding API not responding fast enough (use Geocoder.configure(:timeout => ...) to set limit). this error..
Am getting proper values in each request.

Comment: @phoet I have edited my question with some puts and log info..